# Demonstrating zero phase of vertically symmetrical signals

Tags: dft, phase, time-frequency, symmetry

I'd like to get a zero phase for vertically symmetrical signal (as it done [here, FIGURE 10-7](http://www.dspguide.com/ch10/2.htm)).

For this purpose, I tried to test it on gaussian signal in Python:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0,64,1)

center_left = 0
center_right = 63
sigma = 2.5
signal_left = np.exp(-0.5*((t-center_left)/sigma)**2)
signal_right = np.exp(-0.5*((t-center_right)/sigma)**2)
signal_decomposed_left = np.concatenate([np.zeros(64), signal_right])
signal_decomposed_right = np.concatenate([signal_left, np.zeros(64)])

plt.plot(signal_decomposed_left, marker='o')
plt.plot(signal_decomposed_right, marker='o')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Taking DFT of these signals:

```
FFT_left = np.fft.fft(signal_decomposed_left)
FFT_right = np.fft.fft(signal_decomposed_right)

plt.plot(abs(FFT_left))
plt.plot(abs(FFT_right))
```

we get the identical magnitude for both (as it should be):

[image]

but for the phase:

```
plt.plot(np.angle(FFT_left))
plt.plot(np.angle(FFT_right))
```

[image]

the signals are not identical by modulus, which I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two time domain signals are "buffer flipped" versions of each other, i.e. $x[n] = y[N-1-n]$. In order to do real time flip you need to flip around $n=0$ so you get $x[n] = y[N-n]$ which specifically implies $x[0] = y[0]$

To get the same phase, you should take `signal_decomposed_left` and circularly shift it by one sample so that `signal_decomposed_left[0] = 1`

Then both signals are true time flips of each other, the magnitude will be the same and the phase of one will be the negative of the other.

Comment: would it be more useful to use the signal with odd number of points?

Comment: thank you!) circular shift really helped! my fault was in incorrect usage of even signals property)

Comment: Odd vs even doesn't matter here.